# C# to C++ Interop corrupts float & double arguments for a function on Android phones

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, interop, pinvoke, monogame

I have a very strange bug which  <s>happens only on certain Android phones</s> happens on all tested phones, the techonology is Monogame(C#), the OpenAL library is in C++.

**A TL/DR version: float and double arguments are corrupted when passed by value from C# to C++, but passing them be reference(pointer) works totaly ok. Corrupt float and double arguments also shift all other arguments by one or two places in the argument list.**

Compilers: android-ndk-r10e, Visual Studio 2015.

Link to Android build file configs:
[Android Build Files](https://github.com/KonajuGames/openal-soft/tree/master/build/android/jni)

I have a C++ function like this inside the OpenAL C++ lib:

```
void foo(int i, float x, float y, float z){...}
```

This function is called from C#. The first int param 'i' and the first float param 'x' are passed correctly. But the last two float params, 'y' and 'z', have **one byte of the four bytes corrupted, it's always the same byte (least significant or most significant, can't remember 100% now).**

I tried all possible calling conventions.

The funny thing is if the C++ function has only int params, eg

```
void foo(int,int,int,int)
```

it works completely alright.

I also tried functions with these signatures:

```
void foo(float)
void foo(float,float)
void foo(float,float,float)
void foo(float,float,float,float)
```

And in all cases **the last float** was the one that was not corrupted.

I then try this signature (and a few similar):

```
void foo(int,int,float,int,int,int,float,int,int)
```

and it seems as if each float params shifts the int params that are after it by 4 bytes (aka "shifts by one entire function param" since they are all 4 bytes).

Also something funny that happened in the above signature is that float argument order seemed inverted (the last float argument was replaced by the first one, while integer argument order remained the same).

I also tried using doubles and all possible float/double combinations between C# and C++ calls but nothing worked. Doubles shifted the argument twice as much.

Passing doubles by reference (pointer) works perfectly fine.

Any ideas what could be causing it or clues as what to try next?

Also: is there any way I can debug the interop layer between C# and C++ to see what happens?

Dll imports in C#:

```
[DllImport(AL.Lib, EntryPoint = "ropoFII", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = AL.Style), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
            public static extern void ropoFII(float x, int a, int b);

            [DllImport(AL.Lib, EntryPoint = "ropoFIF", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = AL.Style), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
            public static extern void ropoFIF(float x, int a, float b);

            [DllImport(AL.Lib, EntryPoint = "ropoFIFI", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = AL.Style), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
            public static extern void ropoFIFI(float x, int a, float b, int c);

            [DllImport(AL.Lib, EntryPoint = "ropoIFFF", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = AL.Style), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
            public static extern void ropoIFFF(int a, float b, int c, float d);

            [DllImport(AL.Lib, EntryPoint = "ropoIIFII", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = AL.Style), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
            public static extern void ropoIIFII(int i1, int i2, float f, int i3, int i4);
```

Comment: Add the DllImports from C# to the question

Comment: What ABI/Arch are the phones that you are experiencing a problem on?

Comment: Hm.. as it turns out all phones had this issue.

Comment: Hmm, you have a calling convention mismatch.  `AL.Style` does very little to help us help you of course.  You need to document the processor architecture you target, the C++ compiler you used and the compile options you specified.

Comment: I wrote that I tried all possible calling conventions. The calling conventions are part of the System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention, so they are the "legit" conventions. Maybe a bug in Mono.

Added link to build files.

Comment: I know it's old, but you can not call a C++ methods like that. It needs a class pointer argument, which is hidden by the C++ compiler. Android uses only the cdecl calling convention. You should create a C interface and call it instead of this.